# The parent pointer points to the child class, but I cannot access the methods of that child class

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I have a doubt, in this code I have created a parent class pointer and a child object class, you are not supposed to call the parent class like this (bptr.show()) because the parent object class is not defined, but when I make the parent class point to the child class, I can access the methods of the parent class, but not access the methods of the child class like (bptr.print()), why does that happen?

I would like to know what happened inside, I have never defined the parent class just a pointer class, this should not happen.

```
class Base {
public:
    void virtual mostrar() {
        cout << "CLASE BASE" << endl;
    }
};

class Derivada : public Base {
public:
    void mostrar() {
        cout << "CLASE DERIVADA" << endl;
    }
    void show() {
        cout << "SHOW DERIVADA" << endl;
    }
};


int32_t main() {
    Base* bptr;
    Derivada d;
    bptr = &d;
    bptr->mostrar();
    d.mostrar();
    d.show();
    cout << " - - - - - - -" << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `bptr` points to a `Base` so you can only call methods of `Base`. Its not clear what causes confusion here. If you have a pointer to `Foo` then you can use it to call methods of `Foo` not of another class

Comment: It's because of the types. C++ is **statically typed** (look it up). This means you can access things which are statically known to be accessible from the type of `bptr`. How do you know the type? You look at the declaration. It is declared as `Base* bptr`, so you can access things that are known to be in `Base`.

Comment: my confusion is ( bptr = &d )  is it assumed that if a Base pointer points to a Derived Object address, then why can I only access Base methods and not Derived methods? if bptr is dereferenced it would be Derived?

Comment: C++ does not work this way. It works by looking at the types of the **declarations**. Look at the declaration of `bptr`. It says `Base*`. That's what you have. It does not matter what kind of object `bptr` is pointing at, only how it is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what your are asking. Are you asking about vtables? When you create an variable of a given type (e.g. Base* ptr) you can only access the method signatures defined for that class.

If a method is not declared virtual, you can only access the method from a variable or pointer of the same type. Since show is not virtual, it can only be accessed by a variable of type Derivda or a pointer of type pointer to Derivda.

If that class has methods that are declared virtual, then the first field of the class (which is hidden from the developer) is a pointer to a virtual method dispatch table called a vtable. In your case, the vtable contains a single entity for the method mostrar(). An instance of class Base (i.e. Base b) would have a vtable that contains the address of Base::mosrtar(), while the instance of Derivda has a pointer to a vtable with the first entry has the address of Derivda::mostrar().

Calling bptr->mostrar() is implemented as bptr->vtable[0](btpr) (i.e first parameter is the this pointer, also hidden). If bptr points to an instance of Base then Base::mostrar() will be called.

But since bptr points to a Derivda, the first entry points to the Derivda vtable, and Derivda::mostrar() is called. If show() was virtual instead of non-virtual, it would occupy the second entry in the Derivda vtable which would be longer than the Base vtable (which only has one entry). The compiler will only allow pointers of type Base to access the first entry in a vtable, since it doesn't know if the pointer points to a Base or a Derivda. A pointer of type Derivda would be allowed to use both entries in the vtable.

Notes:

1. This is one implementation of tables that a compiler might use, others are possible.
2. It is much more complicated if multiple inheritance is used.

Comment: One minor correction. If a methods not virtual, it could also be accessed by derived class, so a subclass of Derivda could also access show().